# std vector const_iterator assignment Access violation

Tags: c++, iterator, variable-assignment, runtime-error, stdvector

I'm working on code in which 1 of more variable length object are stored as a vector of all units i.e. assuming each letter is a unit, and the same letter are the same high level object.
the vector may contain something like the following: aaaabbcccdeeffff...

This vector is an internal private variable of a class which has a operator[] defined such that for the vector above

```
 - obj[0] returns an const_iterator to the first "a"
 - obj[1] to the first "b"
 - obj[2] to the first "c" etc.

const AI::GeneArray::const_iterator& AI::Chromosome::operator[](int index) const {
    GeneArray::const_iterator pGene;
    int cIndex;
    for (cIndex=0,pGene = this->vGenes.cbegin();pGene != this->vGenes.cend();pGene++, cIndex++) {
        if (index == cIndex) { break; }
        (*pGene)->EndOfBlock(pGene); }
    return pGene; }
```

Then in another function I have the following

```
AI::GeneArray::const_iterator function = vChromosome[0];
```

This causes an Access violation Error.

The Call stack's above my function are as follows

```
AI.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<AI::Gene *,std::allocator<AI::Gene *> > >::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<AI::Gene *,std::allocator<AI::Gene *> > >(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<AI::Gene *,std::allocator<AI::Gene *> > > & __that)  + 0x2f byte
AI.exe!std::_Iterator012<std::random_access_iterator_tag,AI::Gene *,int,AI::Gene * const *,AI::Gene * const &,std::_Iterator_base12>::_Iterator012<std::random_access_iterator_tag,AI::Gene *,int,AI::Gene * const *,AI::Gene * const &,std::_Iterator_base12>(const std::_Iterator012<std::random_access_iterator_tag,AI::Gene *,int,AI::Gene * const *,AI::Gene * const &,std::_Iterator_base12> & __that)  + 0x2f bytes
AI.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::_Iterator_base12(const std::_Iterator_base12 & _Right)  Line 118
AI.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::operator=(const std::_Iterator_base12 & _Right)  Line 123 + 0x5 bytes
```

The final Call is to

```
_Iterator_base12& operator=(const _Iterator_base12& _Right)
    {   // assign an iterator
        if (_Myproxy != _Right._Myproxy)
            _Adopt(_Right._Myproxy->_Mycont);<- This line
        return (*this);
    }
```

According to my debugger (Visual C++ 2010 Express)

```
_Right._Myproxy->
   _Mycont = CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
   _Myfirstiter = CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

Else where in my project I have similar code using std::list, rather than vector that works correctly

```
parents = new ChromosomeList::const_iterator[C];
*(parents) = --(this->vChromosomes.cend());
for (int i=1;i<C;i++) {
    *(parents+i) = ChromosomeList::const_iterator((*(parents+i-1)));
    (*(parents+i))--; }
```

I've checked the value returned by

vChromosome[0]

this value is of the correct type,

```
const AI::GeneArray::const_iterator &
```

I've search Google for similar problems, All I've been able to find is problem related to looping through a vector using iterator's

i.e.

```
for (AI::GeneArray::const_iterator pGene = Genes.cbegin();pGene != Genes.cend();pGene++)
```

Such Code in my project is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
AI::GeneArray::const_iterator function = vChromosome[0];
```

Should not compile. `function` is an iterator, but you're attempting to set it to the value of the contents of a value. Are you sure you did not want `vChromosome.begin()` instead?

Assuming that's just a typo here, your bug would not be at the point where the assignment happens, your bug would be somewhere before that. `vChromosome` might be empty, for example, in which case attempting to access `operator[](0)` would lead to undefined behavior. (See if the vector is even valid first!)

(Side note,

```
parents = new ChromosomeList::const_iterator[C];
```

why are you managing an array like this manually? Isn't that what `vector` is for? :)
)

Comment: vChromosome, isn't a vector, its a class that contains a vector of sub-object (genes) that make up large objects, when placed in a sequence, the sub-object before detriments what comes next, this creates blocks,
I've defined an the [] operator for this class such that it returns and cont_iterator, to the first gene of the n'th larger object, stored in my vector of genes.

The vector is valid, also the iterator returned by vChromosome[0], I've used my debugger to look at these values.

Comment: @glenflet: If the iterator is valid, doing an assignment of it is not going to invalidate anything or cause access violations. Sounds to me like you've got undefined behavior somewhere in code you're not showing us (like in the `operator[]` of that other class).

Comment: problem solved, I was returning a local variable, in the operator[] function.

Comment: @glenflet: :sigh: -- "Step Into" is your friend in the debugger. :)